# SelectMany inside SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

I tried both of this but didn't work? how to do that?

```
.SelectMany(x => x.SectionEvents).SelectMany(t => t.Section)

.SelectMany(x => x.SectionEvents.SelectMany(t => t.Section))
```

Error :

> The type arguments for method
>   '`System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>,
>   System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)`'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

```
EEvent.List<EEvent>("CalendarPeriodUId", ECalendarPeriod.Current().UId).Value.ToList()
                .SelectMany(x => x.SectionEvents.SelectMany(t => t.Section)).ToFCollection().Bind(ddlSection, "SectionName");
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you what to do.

Comment: Please give a short but complete example. I wouldn't expect you to have to specify the type arguments.

Comment: is this example that suits you, @Jon Skeet?

Comment: I think we need to see the data type EEvent.  i.e. to know what the structure of x is in your initial post and also what x.SectionEvents are

Comment: Are generics involved in this?

Comment: Not really - that's far from a short but complete example demonstrating the problem, isn't it? In particular, I can't copy, paste, compile and see the problem. If you had provided a good example, no-one would have needed to guess...

Comment: sorry for that, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want is to select all Sections from Events through a join table.

```
public class Event
{
    public ICollection<SectionEvent> SectionEvents { get; set; }
}
public class SectionEvent
{
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
}
public class Section
{
    public ICollection<SectionEvent> SectionEvents { get; set; }
}
```

If that so, then what you need is `SelectMany` and `Select`.

```
var q = events.SelectMany(e => e.SectionEvents).Select(se => se.Section);
```

Comment: yes you are right! second SelectMany was wrong. thankyou for your help :)